# Multiple files upload to document library simultaneously & Custom property

Tags: 2007, development, document-library, custom, properties

I have a custom SharePoint 2007 document library which has a custom boolean column "Is it Important".

It works perfectly for all documents if I upload documents one by one regardless of if its a word file or a picture file ".png or .jpg" as I can see property and can even access it through code.

Now if I upload files simultaneously using "multiple files upload" all documents except files with extension .png or .jpg get property "Is it Important". Now I can get value of property but if I try to check if it exists it returns false, wondering if anyone knows what could be the reason.

This is how I am checking custom property,

```
item.Properties.ContainsKey("Is it Important");
```

and getting value as

```
item["Is it Important"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated problem was with

```
 item.Properties.ContainsKey("Is it Important");
```

I couldn't find out what caused this weird behaviour but I find a work around which is going through each SPField and check if my field exists or not using title.

```
private bool IsFieldThere(string ColumnName, SPListItem item)
{
    SPFieldCollection fieldCollection = item.Fields;

    foreach (SPField field in fieldCollection)
    {
        if (field.Title == ColumnName)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I used title as I know it will change but you can use internal name to be on safe side.

Hope it helps.